# React Hight Order Component - Can not use child components in enhanced component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am trying to implement a Higher Order Component in my react app. I have a base form component with all general login, & then I made a ContactForm component which wraps this general component.

The issue is my page become unresponsive & give maximum stack exceeded error when I try to run it. After some research I found that the issue is calling some custom components in render method of general form component. But that is the same syntax I use everywhere in app.

Why react cause this issue & how to resolve it, Am I implementing the HOC logic in wrong way? I need to import those components in the Form since they handle some logic by themselves & help to separate concerns.

Below is code for both general & HOC component.

**Contact Form Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Form from './form'

const createForm = FormComponent =>
    class extends Component {
        render() {
            return <FormComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }

const ContactForm = createForm(Form)

export default ContactForm
```

**Base Form Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import InputText from './input-text'
import SubmitButton from './submit'

class Form extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-form">
                <div className="page-form-fields clearfix">
                    <InputText/>
                </div>
                <SubmitButton />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

**Input Text**

```
class InputText extends Component {
    render() {
        const { type, icon, label, name, placeholder, maxlength, value, disabled, error, errorText } = this.props
        return (
            <div className={`finput ${label && 'labeled'} ${error ? 'has-error' : ''}`}>
                <input
                    type={type || 'text'}
                    name={name}
                    className={`textfield w-input ${error ? 'has-error' : ''}`}
                    maxLength={maxlength}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    value={value}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e)}
                    onBlur={e => this.props.onBlur && this.props.onBlur(e)}
                />
                <label className="fip-label">
                    {label}
                </label>
                {error &&
                    <span className={`fip-info ${error && 'error'}`}>
                        {errorText}
                    </span>}
                {icon && <i className={`icon icon-${icon}`} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Submit Button**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SubmitButton extends Component {
    render() {
        const { response, pending } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="page-form-submit tright half-top-margin">
                {response &&
                    <h4>
                        {response}
                    </h4>}
                <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={e => this.props.onSubmit()} disabled={pending}>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SubmitButton
```

Comment: Can you show InputText and SubmitButton component also?

Comment: @MayankShukla edited

Answer (score 0):

It runs fine here,

```js
const {Component} = React
class Form extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-form">
                <div className="page-form-fields clearfix">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const createForm = FormComponent =>
    class extends Component {
        render() {
            return <FormComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }

const ContactForm = createForm(Form)

ReactDOM.render(<ContactForm />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, It run fine when I use native HTML elements, but somehow it goes in infinite loop when I use imported elements!

Comment: @demonofthemist So probably it's a problem with your `elements`